# Remote GDB debugging

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I've just spent a whole day trying to find a way to enable GDB debugging from [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) or Eclipse. I learned that there are basically two approaches to launch the target application:

- Using ssh (`ssh host gdb`)
- Using gdbserver

I was able to use both approaches to launch gdb remotely and start the application. However, GDB never responds to any breakpoints set in the IDE. Also I can't pause the application to inspect the program state. In Qt Creator I just get an obscure stack trace (I might have been looking at the traces of ssh or gdb actually...).

Can anyone help me to get started?

#### Progress!

I found that with Qt Creator 2.0 there is an feature called "Attach and debug remote application." It's based on gdbserver. The good thing is that it stops on the IDE's breakpoints. However, there are two issues:

- When it hits a breakpoint it only shows assembly code, not the source code.
- GDB often quits because of 'signal received'

I should probably mention that the remote executable is compiled with an older version of GCC than the one installed on my local PC. Perhaps some of the problems are related to this.

#### Update

I should mention that I switched to running [cgdb](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/) on the remote machine via SSH.

The remote Qt Creator-based solution wasn't stable. GDB tends to quit because of mysterious 'signal received' messages.

Comment: Running gdb with --annotate=1 might help with your source code problem. Also, make sure you're compiling with debugging symbols (-g in gcc).

Comment: @Nathon: thanks, I tried using annotate=1 but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: You should be able to stop it stopping by telling it how to handle the signal. Format is `handle <SIGNAL> [no]stop [no]print [no]pass`. The signal name *is* case sensitive, i.e., need caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to peculiarities in our makefile build system the file references contained in the debugging symbols look like this:

```
../src/main.cpp
../../src/utils/logger.cpp
```

This is no problem for GDB, but Qt Creator was unable to map these paths to the actual files. I was able to fix this by adding 'dir' statements in the GDB init file:

```
dir src
dir src/utils
...
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 8):

So that GDB on your host (the machine you develop and compile on, so where you have Qt Creator) you have to give it access to the "symbol file".

I usually don't use Qt Creator, but GDB and gdbserver directly for cross-compiled programs remote-debugging. You could maybe give this a try to be sure that this works for you and maybe then find the missing option in Qt Creator (or maybe this will help you find what is missing).

On the target machine run:

```
gdbserver :5000 yourprogram
```

On the host machine, run gdb and then load the symbol file:

```
(gdb) symbol-file yourprogram
```

On GDB on the host machine, you then have to connect to connect GDB to the remote gdbserver:

```
(gdb) target remote target_ip_address:5000
```

From then you can use GDB on the host controlling the program on the target.

I hope this helps!

Comment: One of the parameters that I have to pass to QtCreator is a local copy of the executable. Am I right in thinking that it will have the symbols embedded when compiled with debugging options (-ggdb)?

Comment: Yes the debug symbols should be included with the -ggdb option. I usually use the -g option that is general, but -ggdb seems even better (it produces additional debug info for use with gdb).

Could it be that you don't have the debug version of the libraries installed on your target ?